# Xorg: Changing display resolution manually via xorg config file

Tags: nvidia, xorg, display, display-resolution, xrandr

I am using Ubuntu 22.10
I want to: **set my display resolution to 1080p using xorg config file as xrandr didn't work for me.**
**Solution worked before:**
In `/usr/lib/X11/xorg.conf.d/10.nvidia.*` i changed the values of `#HorizSync 28.0 - 65.0 #VertRefresh 57.0 - 63.0`
But i can't remember the values now.

Also, suggest me the correct way to change the config file. **I have done this already and system got unbootable**: copied xorg file contains from Nvidia x server app and paste in xorg config file replacing the previous text.
So, please suggest me how can i reboot into my system again.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/06/18/ubuntu-20-10-groovy-gorilla-reaches-end-of-life-on-july-22-2021/ https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades